# Amazon RDS node In AWS Explorer (AWS Toolkit for Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I want to connecting to Amazon Relational Database Service, but I don't see the Amazon RDS node in AWS Explorer even I have a DB instance created and running.

```
Amazon Relational Database Service (N. Virginia) - Service is operating normally
```

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no.....not yet     :-(

Comment: Check the region you're looking in, and that the RDS instance is 'publicly' available (i.e. not hidden or private or has restrictive access)